# Why does my template not work in angular2 component?

Tags: typescript, angular

I have 2 components

first

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {Navbar} from './navbar';
@Component({
    selector: 'app'
    template: `<div class="col-md-12">
    <navbar></navbar>
              </div>`
})
export class App {}
```

and second

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/angular2';
@Component({
    selector: 'navbar',
    template:`<p>Navbar</p>`
 })
 export class Navbar {}
```

But  in root (App) component doesn't show navbar. What am I missing?

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/BcNs2MRWjWKdR6soEwll?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `NavBar` into the `directives` attribute:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app'
  template: `<div class="col-md-12">
    <navbar></navbar>
    </div>`,
  directives: [ Navbar ]
})
```

Answer (score 2):

This depends on which release cycle of `Angular2` is used. In `Angular2 RC6` support for `Directives` inside `@Component` decorator has been removed. `Directives` and `pipes` must be defined in `@NgModule`. In this case it should be defined in `app.module.ts` instead.

app.module.ts

```
// imports...
@NgModule({
   declarations: [
   AppComponent,
   NavbarComponent
],
...
... 
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `Angular 2`, you now have to provide the names of all the components you want to access inside your `component` . Read more about them here: [Multiple Components](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt3.html)

For your question, as @Thierry suggested:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app'
  template: `<div class="col-md-12">
    <navbar></navbar>
    </div>`,
  directives: [ navbar ]
})
```